# Invalid conversion from class pointer to int

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I am unable to figure out what the problem is in the code below

```
class Node
{
    private:
        int index, value;

    public:
        Node(int index=0, int value=0):index(index),value(value){}

        int getIndex()
        {
            return index;
        }

        int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
};


int main()
{
    Node n = new Node(10,10);
    return 0;
}
```

I get

> invalid conversion from Node* to int

Comment: C++ is not Java.  `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: Should be `Node* n = new Node(10,10);`

Comment: `Node n = new Node(10,10);` --> `Node* n = new Node(10,10);`

Comment: Aah. Stupidity. thanks.

Comment: Add an `explicit` to the constructor to avoid the implicit conversion from `int`.

Comment: ...and if that `index` really is to be an index, consider making it `unsigned` to avoid all those warnings coming up e.g. when comparing it to some other size / index value (which _are_ usually `unsigned`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) returns a pointer. You can't assign a pointer to `n`, it's a `Node`. The quick fix would be to change the offending line to `Node * n = new Node(10,10);` or `auto n = new Node(10,10);`.

*However* using `new` is no longer the recommended solution for the dynamic creation of objects in modern c++. Prefer `auto n = std::make_unique<Node>(10, 10);` instead which makes `n` a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). By using smart pointers, you relieve yourself from having to manually track ownership and from having to remember to `delete` your object exactly once. You also make your code much more robust in case of unexpected exceptions. You'll need to `#include <memory>`. See [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) :

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto n = std::make_unique<Node>(10,10);
    return 0;
}
```

Though in this case, it doesn't seem like dynamic allocation is required. Simply using `Node n{10, 10};` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

### If you want it on the stack

```
Node n(10, 10);
```

The object will be made on the stack. It goes out of scope at the end of the function, or even before it (for instance if it was declared in a loop).

### If you want it on the heap

```
Node *n = new Node(10, 10);
```

The object is allocated on the heap, and a pointer to it is on the stack. It behaves more you'd expect it with Java's "references". The object will not be deleted when the pointer goes out of scope. Instead, `delete` has to be called at some point or else the memory will be leaked (unlike with Java's "references", which are garbage collected).

Comment: Better yet, use a smart pointer and never call `new` and `delete`. Also always useful to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/485343

Answer (score 1):

When using the new argument you need to use a pointer.  The line

```
Node n = new Node(10,10);
```

Should be

```
Node* n = new Node(10,10);
```

The error message is because the value returned from new is a numeric location in memory and the closest datatype the compiler knows to represent this is an int.

Comment: A location in memory doesn't look like an int.

Comment: OT: looks like the compiler is trying to create a Node from int using its constructor. Unless you really want `Node n = 5;` to succeed, make the constructor `explicit`